# Allow web service to serve both request http and https?

Tags: asp.net, web-services, web-config, wcf-binding

```
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="Complete_Html5.CompleteService.CompleteServiceAspNetAjaxBehavior" name="Complete_Html5.CompleteService.Complete">
        <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_Complete" contract="Complete_Html5.CompleteService.Complete" />
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
      </service>
      <service name="Complete_Html5.Service1" behaviorConfiguration="Complete_Html5.Service1ServiceAspNetAjaxBehavior">
        <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="Complete_Html5.Service1" />
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
      </service>
    </services>

    <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="Complete_Html5.Service1AspNetAjaxBehavior">
          <enableWebScript />
        </behavior>
        <behavior name="Complete_Html5.CompleteService.CompleteServiceAspNetAjaxBehavior">
          <enableWebScript />
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>      
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="Complete_Html5.CompleteService.CompleteServiceAspNetAjaxBehavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
        </behavior>        
        <behavior name="Complete_Html5.Service1ServiceAspNetAjaxBehavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
        </behavior>        
      </serviceBehaviors>      
    </behaviors>

    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_Complete" closeTimeout="00:10:00" openTimeout="00:10:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:10:00" allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" maxBufferPoolSize="10485760" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered" useDefaultWebProxy="true">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />

          <security mode="None">
            <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None" realm="" />
            <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
          </security>
        </binding>
        <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_Complete1" closeTimeout="00:10:00" openTimeout="00:10:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:10:00" allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered" useDefaultWebProxy="true">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384" maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
          <security mode="None">
            <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None" realm="" />
            <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
          </security>
        </binding>
        <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_Service1" closeTimeout="00:10:00" openTimeout="00:10:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:10:00" allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" maxBufferPoolSize="10485760" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered" useDefaultWebProxy="true" messageEncoding="Text">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
          <security mode="None">
            <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None" realm="" />
            <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
          </security>
        </binding>
        <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_Service11" />
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="http://www.examplete.com:83/CompleteService/Complete.svc" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_Complete" contract="Complete_Html5.CompleteService.Complete" name="BasicHttpBinding_Complete" />
      <endpoint address="http://www.examplete.com:83/CompleteService/Complete.svc" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_Complete1" contract="PMCService.Complete" name="BasicHttpBinding_Complete1" />
      <endpoint address="http://www.examplete.com:83/Service1.svc" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_Service1" contract="ReportService.Service1" name="BasicHttpBinding_Service1" />
      <endpoint address="http://www.examplete.com:83/Service1.svc" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_Service11" contract="ReportService.Service1" name="BasicHttpBinding_Service11" />
    </client>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

Above is the `service` setting in `web.config` what changes I have to make so that I could use both hits `http` and `https` while accessing `website`??

We have added ssl certificate to server and have unchecked `required ssl` from website `ssl` certificate setting.

[image]
 It it working fine `http` but when hits come is website is with `https` it's throwing error as:

> The provided URI scheme `https` is invalid; Expected `http`. Parameter
>   name: via.

How to solve this so that allow both hits `http` and `https`?

> This is specially when we calling web service method.!

Have tried by adding `httpsGetEnabled="true"` in serviceMetadata element but still not working..!

Comment: @Hi there, please suggest something for above mentioned isssue..! :-(

Comment: I'm looking for solution this issue from last week, I posted this issue on number of forums but just they provids links which was also not helpful for me.
Even I'm asking about this issue on this forum no. of times is there no solution to do this. But as I saw number of places develeper did that and that works 
fine as they said as per commnet but in my case that was not helpful, I don't know, whether I making mistake to solve or any other else reason for that not
to works. Plase can someone suggest what to do??

Answer (score 1):

try this

you already have the

```
<serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true"...
```

so you will need a separate http and https binding , thus:

```
<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="NoSecurity">
      <security mode="None" />
    </binding>
    <binding name="SSL">
      <security mode="Transport">
        <transport clientCredentialType="None" />
      </security>
    </binding>
  </basicHttBinding>
</bindings>
```

then apply those to a couple of endpoints..

```
<endpoint 
  address="Basic" 
  binding="basicHttpBinding"
  bindingConfiguration="NoSecurity"
  contract="Complete_Html5.CompleteService.Complete" />
<endpoint 
  address="SSL" 
  binding="basicHttpBinding"
  bindingConfiguration="SSL"
  contract="Complete_Html5.CompleteService.Complete" />
```

you would then get your 2 endpoints

http://path/to/your.service.svc/basic

https://path/to/your.service.svc/ssl

you probably also want to add this to your service behavious

```
<serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
```

so you can get the metadata over https also